# Angularjs, show/hide row's table with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html-table, angularjs-ng-repeat

Sorry, i'm new to ng-repeat. How can i show/hide row  table that is using ng-repeat? And the most bottom row is shown if dropdown value is 1.

```
    var i ;
    $scope.names = [];
    $scope.tmp = [];
    for(i=0;i<=10;i++){
        $scope.tmp[i] = i;
        $scope.names[i] = "name "+ i;
    }
    $scope.isShow = true
```

html

```
<select>
        <option ng-repeat="x in tmp">{{x}}</option>
</select>
 <table>
   <tr ng-show='isShow' ng-repeat="name in names">
     <td>{{name}}</td>
   </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: it's not exactly clear what you are trying to accomplish here, but in general, if you are generating multiple items that need to be shown or hidden independently of each other, each item has to track it's own visibility, meaning a single `isShow` property won't be enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you must add property `isShow` for each `name` in `names`?
Or create array with visible status for each `name`.

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .directive('appDir', appDir);

angular.bootstrap(
  document.getElementById('root'), ['app']
);

function appDir() {
  return {
    template: `
       <table>
          <tr
              ng-repeat="name in names"
              ng-show="name.isShow"
          >
              <td>
                  {{name.title}}
              </td>
          </tr>
       </table>
       <select
          ng-model="selectedName"
          ng-options="x as x for x in tmp"
          ng-change="hiddenName()"
       >
    `,
    link: appDirLink
  }
}

function appDirLink($scope) {
  $scope.names = [];
  $scope.tmp = [];
  $scope.hiddenName = hiddenName;
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    $scope.names[i] = {
      id: i,
      title: 'name_' + i,
      isShow: true
    };
    $scope.tmp[i] = i;
  }

  function hiddenName() {
     $scope.names.map((name, index) => {
        name.isShow = (index < $scope.selectedName) ? true : false;
     });
  }

}
```

```html
<div id="root">
    <app-dir></app-dir>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. My idea is if dropdown is 2, then 2 row ( from bottom) is show, and 8 row above is hidden.

Comment: I change my example. See `hiddenName` function

Comment: What is $scope.names.map((name, index) => {
        name.isShow = (index < $scope.selectedName) ? true : false;
     }); doing? What is index?